# Group by in Update is not working to update column from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Below query is giving error: Incorrect syntex near group.

Please help

```
UPDATE patient 
SET CreationDateTime = MIN(doc.creationdatetime)
FROM Patient patient 
INNER JOIN Document doc ON patient.patientid = doc.patientid
GROUP BY patient.patientid
```

Comment: Not really what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to update each patients CreatingDateTime with the earliest creationdatetime from the Document table?